# Is str_replace with an array the right way to format a person's last name?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Out of a MySQL database I have a list of names like

- Smith
- Frank
- Dent MD
- Smith Sr.
- Jones, jr.
- Smith-Jones
- O'Toole

I need to get that list to be

- smith
- frank
- dent
- smith
- jones
- smith-jones
- otoole

By format I mean I only want the "main" part of the last name eliminating any

- non-alphanumeric characters
- spaces
- Titles (jr, sr, MD, etc...)

I realize in some cases this is "changing" the person's name but it's not being used in any way that they see.

Right now I am doing something like:

```
$toReplace  = array('.', ',', '-', ' jr', ' sr', ' MD', ' DO', "'", ' ');
//For each result from my query
    $lname = str_replace($toReplace, '', $row_rsgetUsers['lname']);
    $lname = strtolower($lname);
```

Then, after awhile a name shows up like `Wright CISA` so I then have to update my `$toReplace` array to account for that.  (I have no control over the input of the names)

Is that the best way to go about doing this or is there a better way/library out there I should be using that eliminates the need for me to manually update my `$toReplace` array occasionally?

Comment: First of all, define "standardise". What is the "standard"?

Comment: personally I'd use a regexp, which matches the part you're looking for: `#^([a-z'-])+#i` then str_replace the single-quote and lowercase the result.

Comment: What if "jr" or "sr" is inside person's name? This will fail

Comment: The person named 'O'Toole' might not be very happy about changing his name to 'otoole'.

Comment: Note, the replacement of `'-'` will end up changing "Smith-Jones" into "smithjones".  It might not be worth the trouble to correct that while still replacing `'-'` elsewhere.

Comment: @AlmaDo - You're correct - I've updated my example

Comment: @deceze - Apologies, I changed the title and question a bit - "format" might be a better term.  I've updated the question with how I'm looking to format the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you asked. Though you could've find it yourself here at stack: [Replace all characters except letters, numbers, spaces and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442174/replace-all-characters-except-letters-numbers-spaces-and-underscores) [How do I remove everything after a space in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177788/how-do-i-remove-everything-after-a-space-in-php)

```
<?php
    $user_list = array('Smith', 'Frank', 'Dent MD', 'Smith Sr.', 'Jones, jr.', 'Smith-Jones', "O'Toole");
    print_r($user_list);
    $string = "O'Toole";
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach($user_list as $user_string){
        //remove special chars and convert Upper case letters to lower case
        $string = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $user_string));
        //remove everything after space, case example: Jones, jr.
        $string = explode(' ', $string);
        $string = $string[0];
        //assign "standartized?" string 
        $temp_array[] = $string;
    }
    print_r($temp_array);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Smith
    [1] => Frank
    [2] => Dent MD
    [3] => Smith Sr.
    [4] => Jones, jr.
    [5] => Smith-Jones
    [6] => O'Toole
)
Array
(
    [0] => smith
    [1] => frank
    [2] => dent
    [3] => smith
    [4] => jones
    [5] => smithjones
    [6] => otoole
)
```

Comment: Except for a situation where the last name is two names separated by a space this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that will replace all non-ASCII characters with ASCII characters, make a string lowercase, etc ( [The Source CookBook](http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php) ).

```
$names = array( 'Smith', 'Frank', 'Dent MD', 'Smith Sr.', 'Jones, jr.', 'Smith-Jones', "O'Toole" );

foreach( $names as &$value ) {
    $value = slugify( $value );
}

print_r( $names );

function slugify( $text ) {

    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);  
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    /**
     * //IGNORE//TRANSLIT to avoid errors on non translatable characters and still translate other characters
     * //TRANSLIT to out_charset transliteration is activated
     * //IGNORE, characters that cannot be represented in the target charset are silently discarded
    */
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $text);   
    $text = strtolower(trim($text));

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    return empty($text) ? '' : $text ;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => smith
    [1] => frank
    [2] => dent-md
    [3] => smith-sr
    [4] => jones-jr
    [5] => smith-jones
    [6] => o-toole
)
```

Comment: This would work except for the fact that I need to eliminate the -md, -sr, -jr, etc.

Comment: If that 'slugs' are used internally, then should not be a problem if they have some titles, what if a person has two titles, or if the titles are before the person's name. There are all sort of combinations to worry about.